# Grails Spring Security not keeping user logged in after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, spring-security

I have a create view where if the user is not logged in, a login form is show at the start of the view. If the user tries to login, an ajax call is made to spring to log the user in. This works as my logic inside the success is called. What my success function does is hide the login form and show a "Post" button at the bottom of the page.

If the user continues to fill out the form and clicks the "Post" button, in the controller when I check for the logged in user like so

```
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser;
```

it shows that the user is null.

Using the same logic, I have a login form in the header of all my pages for a quick login feature. When the user logs in using the header, the header changes to show he is logged in and a link to the "Post" page is inserted in the header.

If the user goes to the "Post" page using this new link, and completes the form, now the same backend code as above has the proper user information and is not null.

Is there a reason why the login user is erased on the POST call in this scenario?

here is my ajax calls:

header:

```
$("#LoginButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/j_spring_security_check',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                j_username: $("#username").val(),
                j_password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/layout/renderNavBarLoggedIn',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#navbar").empty();
                        $("#navbar").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        alert('Fail!1');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert('Fail!2');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

post page:

```
$("#login-button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/j_spring_security_check',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            j_username: $("#username").val(),
            j_password: $("#password").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/project/showPostButton',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".omb_login").hide();
                    $("#post-button-container").empty();
                    $("#post-button-container").html(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    alert('Fail!1');
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert('Fail!2');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, both the header and the login form had username and password ids and I just renamed the ids for the login form.